# ViewModel is created again for the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, android-architecture-components

I create viewmodel in MainFragment:

```
 @Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
   ...
    MainViewModel mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
   ...
}
```

When user select item then navigate to Details fragment, this transaction is added to backstack.

```
 getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.root, Details.newInstance())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
```

When user press back in Details fragment, everything is ok, but if user rotate device in Details fragment and press back then:

- new instance of ViewModel is created for MainFragment
- old instance is still alive ( method   onCleared not called)

Is this a bug in ViewModelProviders? How to fix this? 
In my opinion ViewModel should be restored.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a confirmed issue. The fix is available in the AndroidX 1.0.0-alpha2 release.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73644080

Answer (score 3):

This is not really obvious, but when you call `addToBackStack`, the fragment manager will not destroy your fragment, just stops it, when new `replace` transaction comes. You basically have two items on the backstack now, both being instances of your `Details`. Since `onDestroy` was never called for the first one, its `ViewModel's` `onCleared` was never called either.

In your case, simply checking if your fragment is currently in the container (e.g. via `FragmentManager.findFragment()` and NOT replacing it in such situation, should be enough.

Comment: I don't understand this explanation. "The fragment manager will not destroy your fragment" - ok so far (I assume you mean the main fragment), but then "two items... both instances of your details" - wouldn't be the two instances on the back stack at this point the main fragment and the details fragment?

Comment: I honestly cannot remember what I meant here, but you're right that I have a mistake int the sentence about both instances being Details. I'm pretty sure about the fragment not being destroyed and therefore onCleared not called, though.

Answer (score 1):

You are use link to fragment but need to Activity use:

```
MainViewModel mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(MainViewModel.class);
```

Comment: This is bad idea. If I do this,  every ViewModel will by live as long as activity. I don't want that. I want ViewModel live as long as fragment.

Comment: in which method you are adding fragment?

Comment: I replece fragments in callback when user select item in recyclerview

Comment: Ok, move your viewModel init to `onCreate()`  of Fragment and call `setRetainable(true);`

Comment: Do you mean    setRetainInstance(true); ? this don't work, the same situation.