# Android ViewModel recreated when its Host Activity was not in the top of Activity Stack and the device was rotated

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-mvvm

I am in the following scenario:

I have an `OnboardActivity` which contains a `ViewModel`, I can rotate this `OnboardActivity` many times and the `ViewModel` persist across configuration changes without issues.

However, if I launch another `Activity(FirebaseAuthActivity)` on top of this one (`OnboardActivity`) with `startActivityForResult(...)`, and then in `FirebaseAuthActivity` I rotate the device and press the back button. When the `OnboardActivity` is brought to the top of the stack it recreates the `ViewModel` instance again.

Is this the normal behavior of `ViewModel` in architecture components?

Is there a way I can tell the `OnboardActivity` to not finish when it is pop from the stack with a screen orientation different than the one it was saved?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly - no it's not normal behavior for a `ViewModel` to be destroyed when its' associated activity is in the background. This includes when you call `startActivityForResult`. I just tested out whether I'm seeing this bug and can't replicate - can you add your code which starts the new Activity? VMs are destroyed when you call finish(), navigate back or up out of the activity, swipe the activity off of the Overview screen, or in rare cases when your app is in the background and the OS needs to free up resources.

Comment: I also tried a simple project just to simulate the scenario. Unfortunately, I could not reproduce the issue, maybe because the original project has more fragments in the FragmentManager, who knows. I opened a bug here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71833712

Comment: Hmm yeah, a simple example would really help - Have you seen this SO post? Behavior mentioned seems similar to what you're experiencing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44588430/viewmodel-is-created-again-for-the-fragment

Answer (score 2):

I have answered to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51472990/9342060), This might help you to fix your self as of now.

This was a bug from an android framework. [Bug details](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73644080)

The fix is available in 28.0.0-alpha3 and AndroidX 1.0.0-alpha3

But if you don't want to update to above versions now itself, Then you can solve like this (I know this is a bad solution but I didn't see any other good way)

In your activity override onDestroy method and save all the required fields to local variables before calling super.onDestroy. Now call super.onDestroy then Initialize your ViewModel again and assign the required fields back to your new instance of ViewModel

about [isFinishing](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#isFinishing())

Below code is in Kotlin:

```
override fun onDestroy() {

  if (!isFinishing) { //isFinishing will be false in case of orientation change
      val oldViewModel = obtainViewModel()

      val requiredFieldValue = oldViewModel.getRequiredFieldValue()

      super.onDestroy

     val newViewModel = obtainViewModel()

     if (newViewModel != oldViewModel) { //View Model has been destroyed
          newViewModel.setRequiredFieldValue(requiredFieldValue)
      }
  } else {
     super.onDestroy
  }
 }

private fun obtainViewModel(): SampleViewModel {
      return ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SampleViewModel::class.java)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, the Activity that was causing me this error is a third party Activity. It is the FirebaseLoginActivity, so I will have to wait until they upgrade their support library dependency or maybe override their activity. Anyways, I had locked the screen to a portrait only which I think it gives a better user experience overall. By the way, apart from videos, I have not seen another good case allowing landscape in phones.

Answer (score 1):

I Have notice the same issue when using ViewModel and made some research, here is the scenario:

- 1) open ActivityA
  -gets ViewModel with reference: TestViewModel@e71fab8
- 2) rotate device
  -gets ViewModel with reference: TestViewModel@e71fab8
- 3) open ActivityB
- 4) rotate device
- 5) press back (finish Activity B)
- 6) Activity A comes back from stack
  -gets ViewModel with reference: TestViewModel@260072e

I have tested with two kinds of ViewModel, with factory and default creation method:

- ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(TestViewModel::class.java)
- ViewModelProviders.of(this,
  factory).get(DashboardViewModel::class.java)

Both Activities extends AppCompatActivity class.

It was tested with arch version 1.1.1 and 1.1.0.

-

Comment: Yeap, the issue has been confirmed here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72690424
It seems related to Activity B changing the windowIsTranslucent state. I did the same test you did with Activity B as a simple Activity that inherits from AppCompatActivity and I could not reproduce it. Happens when Activity B modifies certain parameters related to the android window.

Answer (score 0):

This is also happening to me when opening the camera or the gallery to pick an image. Rotate the screen when in the camera / gallery and come back, and the view model gets recreated.

Comment: Fortunately the issue has been fixed https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73644080